# How can I check an AS3 2D array for a matching object?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am using an Actionscript 3 "faux" 2D array to store tiles in a game, and I want to allow my players to move only to valid tiles. The array is built up like "array[x][y]", and I have the values in place, knowing both the array values and the player movement values. I know indexOf works with regular arrays, but how could I check a 2D array?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by faux 2d array? show some code.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee9.html if you know the player x, y and you store the tiles using the x, y coordinate system I don't see what the issue is with checking x, y in the 2D array for a valid tile (or bounds checking each separately then checking for a valid tile)

Answer (score 0):

If your array instance is `myArray`, you can use a for loop as following:

```
private function search(element:Object):Point
{
    for (var columIndex:int = 0; columIndex < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        var rowIndex:int = myArray[columIndex].indexOf(element);
        if (rowIndex != -1)
        {
            return new Point(columIndex, rowIndex);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where the `Point` class would be something like that:

```
package
{
    public class Point
    {
        public var x:int;
        public var y:int;

        public function Point(x:int, y:int)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As3 does not have native 2D array classes, so you have to use nested arrays in order to get a multidimensional array working - hence faux. (Whoops, posted this on the wrong answer)

Answer (score 0):

In order to run `indexOf()` on a 2D array, you should iterate through the nested arrays, returning 2D coordinates (use `flash.geom.Point` for that, or any other class you tailor for this). But you will do better if you would check if player moves to a valid location by querying that location right in the array, and check its validity.

```
function isValid(player:Player,playerWantsToMoveTo:Point):Boolean {...}
```